# Access zk internationalization labels in another eclipse project

Tags: zk

I have multiple projects in my eclipse workspace and would like to share the i3-labels files for internationalization between them. How do I move the internationalization labels into a folder (commonProject) in another project, and get  to see them?

Right now in zk.xml I have:

```
<system-config>
    <label-location>/commonProject/labels/i3-label_es_MX.properties</label-location>
    <label-location>/commonProject/labels/i3-label_fr_FR.properties</label-location>
    <label-location>/commonProject/labels/i3-label.properties</label-location>
</system-config>
```

But I can't access the labels. (I get a null pointer)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current path is a relative servlet path, but the servlet
does not load your labels, cos they arn't deployed.
You could add a system path, load the labels from a DB or URL,
as discribed in the [ZK-Doc](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Internationalization/Labels#Loading_Labels_from_Multiple_Resources).

So it could look like

```
<system-config>
    <label-location>file:///path/to/my/projects/commonProject/labels/i3-label_es_MX.properties</label-location>
    <label-location>file:///path/to/my/projects/commonProject/labels/i3-label_fr_FR.properties</label-location>
    <label-location>file:///path/to/my/projects/commonProject/labels/i3-label.properties</label-location>
</system-config>
```